# When does $ \| Cx \|_{\mathbb{R}^2}^2 = \langle Cx, x\rangle$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When can one write the euclidean norm as an inner product?

i.e. if :

$$ \| Cx \|^2 = \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2$$

then, when can we write the norm as follows:

$$ \| Cx \|^2 = \langle Cx, x\rangle$$

I thought that $\| v \| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$, so it seems weird that $ \| Cx \|^2 = \langle Cx, x\rangle$ could ever hold, but maybe the is a clever way to construct the matrix C to make that work? Am I missing something or did the professor made a mistake on the board?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. The usual Euclidean norm is characterized by $||x||^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2$.

Comment: It might help to notice that $\left\langle Cx, x \right\rangle = x^T Cx$. This can be observed by writing out the first few elements of the matrix-vector product $Cx$.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of your question is

> For which matrices $C$ is it true that $\langle x, Cx \rangle = \|Cx\|^2$?

In terms of matrix multiplication, we could say that $C$ is such a matrix iff for every $x \in \Bbb R^n$, we have
$$
x^T C x = (Cx)^T Cx \implies\\
x^T C x = x^T (C^TC) x
$$
Note that $x^TAx = x^TBx$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$ iff $A + A^T = B + B^T$.

Since $C^TC$ is symmetric, we note that $x^T C x = x^T (C^TC) x$ for all $x$ iff
$$
C + C^T = 2C^TC
$$

Comment: I don't think I understood what you meant by $A+A^T = B+B^T$, section of your answer. I thought that $x^TAx = x^TBx$ if $A=B$ ...

Comment: For example, take $$A=\pmatrix{0&2\\0&0},\quad B=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$$

Comment: The implication that you've stated is correct, but its converse is not.